# Notification shows not in exact time

Tags: android, android-notifications

I know that this topic is explained fairly well and there are a lot of tutorials. But maybe I'm too new in android to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I need to implement support of set of reminders. And notification should be shown exactly every Monday at 15 pm. I checked a lot of tutorials and similar questions on this site but anyway notification shows, somehow, randomly.

How do I test implementation:

1. Current time is 14:55
2. I set reminder on Monday at 15:00
3. And right after SAVE notification is shown.
4. Because of (just for example) I set repeat period in 20 sec, this notification is shown again and again with delay of 20 sec. But current time is still between 14:55 and 15:00.

And my task is to run notification at 15:00 or a liitle later. But not before.

**set repeating notification**

```java
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, (int) reminder.id, intent, 0);

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminder.time.hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, reminder.time.minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 20000, pendingIntent);
```

**BTW**

my min SDK version is 7, so I cannot use methods like *setExact()*

android version on tested device is 4.4.2

Thanks

Comment: looks like result is the same (with set the targetSdkVersion to "18"). In general notifications are shown immediately, but sometimes there are no notifications at all ((

Comment: Example: current time is 16:30. Reminder is set to 17:00. The difference between 2 targetSdkVersion: 1) <19: notification is shown immediately at 16:30. At 17:00 nothing happen. 2) ==19: notification is shown not immediately, could be 16:30, could be 16:31. But at 17:00 result is the same - nothing ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the alarm you set it with `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` instead of `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`. Simple bug ;).

Basically setting the alarm to 'now' every time, ignoring your calendar object.

Comment: thanks for the reply) but result is the same. I set reminder an hour ahead, but notification shows immediately and the same result is every 20 seconds ((

Comment: Are you sure..? Please update your question with the fixed code to further investigate.

Comment: no, spending a lot of hours with this task i am no longer sure of anything :) Running tests of this 8 times, 3 of them was without notifications at all and the rest 5 showed notification immediately and then every 20 seconds

Comment: well the code you have posted here is obviously executing the alarm  instantly because that's what you tell it to do. If you want your new problem solved please update your question, otherwise I can't do much to assist...

Comment: Thank you for your help. It really was simple bug ;) And in scope of this question I can accept it as correct. The next question is how to support notifications for every day (or some selected days). Looks like (if I understand it correctly) I have to store selected days somewhere is the db and check them in BroadcastReceiver (which shows notification).